# Prevent system properties/variables being evaluated in Java properties?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am using Spring to load properties:

```
<util:properties id="service-properties">
        ...
        <prop key="postScript"></prop>
        ... 
</util:properties>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="propertyConfigurer"><property name="properties" ref="service-properties" />
</bean>
```

However, one of the properties can have a value like the following (this is a camel xml simple language snippet):

```
postScript=<setBody><simple>${in.header.type}</simple></setBody>
```

The problem, is when I get the value of this property, it is:

```
postScript=<setBody><simple></simple></setBody>
```

I think it seems to be trying to resolve the ${in.header.type} variable, thinking it is a system variable maybe?

I'd like to know how to stop this variable being resolved? I've tried escaping it with quotes but no good.

Comment: Try the option mentioned in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162346/escape-property-reference-in-spring-property-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer for this from the Camel docs :-)

http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

> Alternative syntax
>
> From Camel 2.5 onwards you can also use the alternative syntax which uses $simple{ } as placeholders.
> This can be used in situations to avoid clashes when using for example Spring property placeholder together with Camel.