# Spring: How to avoid automatic property resolving in particular placeholder

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a configuration file with fields where should values be injected. I have one property:

```
@Value("${other.app.start.script:}")
private String startScript;
```

The value which injects in this property is smth like this:

`/app/${version}/otherAppStarter.bat`

So, Spring is trying to resolve ${version} when Context is starting. But I need this value be resolved at other time during some processes will run. And the ${version} might be changed during the main app is working.

Is there any way to tell Spring not to resolve ${version} placeholder.
I can change ${version} to something like #[version] then Spring will not resolve this placeholder, but maybe there is the way to use some native Spring features.

Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape property reference in Spring property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162346/escape-property-reference-in-spring-property-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can register a `static` bean which extends `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and override its method `convertPropertyValue`.

```java
public class MyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        if (originalValue.contains("${version}")) {
            return originalValue;
        }

        return super.convertPropertyValue(originalValue);
    }
}
```

In case, you are using a Java configuration via `@PropertySource`, you will need to override the method `doProcessProperties` as well, as described in Spring Jira [SPR-8928](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8928):

```java
@Override
protected void doProcessProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess,
                                   StringValueResolver valueResolver) {

    super.doProcessProperties(beanFactoryToProcess,
            new StringValueResolver() {
                @Override
                public String resolveStringValue(String strVal) {
                    return convertPropertyValue(valueResolver.resolveStringValue(strVal));
                }
            });
}
```

An example of Java configuration could look like this:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:saml/saml.properties")
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer myPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new MyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```