# Could not read properties if it contains dollar symbol (${var})

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, template-engine, properties-file

I have property file with following content:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT=Field ${fieldName} is invalid or missing.
```

I read this using spring configuration:

```
@PropertySource("error_messages_en.properties")
@Configuration
public static class ErrorMessagesEn {
     @Value("${INVALID_ARGUMENT}")
    private String invalidArgument;
}
```

But after application start I see:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'fieldName' in value "Ïîëå ${fieldName} íåêîððåêòíî çàïîëíåíî èëè ïðîïóùåíî."
```

I need `${fieldName}` because I want to use repacer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655963/2674303

How to avoid this error?

Comment: Is not clear to me where you change the placeholder. I think you miss to explain this part.

Comment: @Mario Santini I do it in java code. Library I use for this linked in question

Comment: The link is about another answer and didn't explain how you use it in your code.

Comment: I want to read value to string with content **Field ${fieldName} is invalid or missing.** and then replace **${fieldName}** with value from runtime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape property reference in Spring property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162346/escape-property-reference-in-spring-property-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape `${fieldName}` as it is not defined as a Spring property.

You could have a look at this question: [Escape property reference in spring property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162346/escape-property-reference-in-spring-property-file) and the associated answer.

You should write this instead:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT=Field #{'$'}{fieldName} is invalid or missing.
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' in value "${INVALID_ARGUMENT}"

Comment: I have tested and I do not produce this issue. Are you sure it is linked? If you set `INVALID_ARGUMENT=foo` are you getting the issue too?

Comment: looks like encoding issue, but I am not sure

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a yaml file you need to surround the value with quotes

argument: "Field #{'$'}{fieldName} is invalid or missing."