# How to set a value with '$' in content of a @Value in Spring

Tags: java, spring

It's a common way to use @Value in Spring to load value from propertie files, like:
`@Value("${xxxx}")`

Now I come cross a situation that I need to set the content of value like `".... now: ${now}...."` , because I need to use it as a template in `org.beetl.core.GroupTemplate`

here is the example:

```
@Value("${myTemplate}")
private String myTemplate;
```

and the application.properties:

```
myTemplate = template:${now}
```

then Spring find the `$` in `${now}` and parsing it as a placeholder and give the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'now' in value
```

And I'm not willing and able to set `setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to false;

Also I tried to replace the content to `....now:&#36;{now}....`, however I tried many ways to convert the `&#36;` to `$` in java code, but none of them worked;

So is there any other ways to deal with this case?

Thanks for your helping and time.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
template:#{'$'}{now}
```

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162346/escape-property-reference-in-spring-property-file)

Comment: Someone has already answered in my question and given the Original answer link before , I don't know why he deleted the answer.  Besides, this not work for me, but `@Value("#{'$'}{myTemplate}")`  this works for me